# How to prevent logging noise during startup in @SpringBootTest?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
                    properties = "logging.level.root=OFF")
public class MyTest {
         @Test
         public void test() {}
}
```

As a result of the simple test above, I'm getting much startup noise logged. This was not the case before upgrading to spring-boot-2.x.
How can I prevent this noise?

Especially, my Intellij IDE logs those statements in *red*, which is even more confusing as the test itself passes...

```
Jul 31, 2018 1:55:57 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration
INFO: Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [MyTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
Jul 31, 2018 1:55:57 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractContextLoader generateDefaultLocations
INFO: Could not detect default resource locations for test class [MyTest]: no resource found for suffixes {-context.xml, Context.groovy}.
Jul 31, 2018 1:55:57 PM org.springframework.test.context.support.AnnotationConfigContextLoaderUtils detectDefaultConfigurationClasses
INFO: Could not detect default configuration classes for test class [MyTest]: MyTest does not declare any static, non-private, non-final, nested classes annotated with @Configuration.
Jul 31, 2018 1:55:57 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper getOrFindConfigurationClasses
INFO: Found @SpringBootConfiguration MyApp for test class MyTest
Jul 31, 2018 1:55:58 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper getDefaultTestExecutionListenerClassNames
INFO: Loaded default TestExecutionListener class names from location [META-INF/spring.factories]: [org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener]
Jul 31, 2018 1:55:58 PM org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper getTestExecutionListeners
INFO: Using TestExecutionListeners: [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@1a4013, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextBeforeModesTestExecutionListener@1b6e1eff, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoTestExecutionListener@306f16f3, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@702b8b12, org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener@22e357dc, org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionalTestExecutionListener@49912c99, org.springframework.test.context.jdbc.SqlScriptsTestExecutionListener@10163d6, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithSecurityContextTestExecutionListener@2dde1bff, org.springframework.security.test.context.support.ReactorContextTestExecutionListener@15bbf42f, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.ResetMocksTestExecutionListener@550ee7e5, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.restdocs.RestDocsTestExecutionListener@5f9b2141, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.client.MockRestServiceServerResetTestExecutionListener@247d8ae, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.MockMvcPrintOnlyOnFailureTestExecutionListener@48974e45, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverTestExecutionListener@6a84a97d]
```

Maybe it has to do using log4j2?

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Use `logging.level.root=off`

Comment: I tried, but no success...

Comment: That is strange. It works for me with Spring Boot v2.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: Could you as a test add the `log4j2` dependency configuration as added above? Maybe this might be the cause?

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you try reporting it with Spring, or make any other progress? I can get rid of almost all the output by manually specifying `@ContextConfiguration(locations = ..., classes = ...)` and `@TestExecutionListeners(inheritListeners = true)`, but the last line is still there. In addition, I wonder why this is logged to `stderr` (red) instead of `stdout`?

Comment: @Jodiug check out my latest answer on this question :), i hope that resolves your problem

Comment: In addition to logging levels there are more settings: `debug: false` and `trace: false` in application properties, [more info in docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.6.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-console-output)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Edited**

Create **logback-test.xml** in your test resource (**\test\resources**),
Then put bellow snippet into it

```
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

> It prints default system INFOs, not startup noise logs. (As you
>   wanted)

And dependency of test can be as follows

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and this is a way to silence the messages. I am still missing something though - this also hides other, useful messages. INFO logs should normally go to stdout. Do you know why the log output shows up in red (stderr) and not white (stdout)?

Comment: ^ Cannot edit. When I specify `properties = ["logging.pattern.console="]`, the log messages still appear in stderr. Same for `logback-test.xml`.

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, you mean that you want INFO s in console , but in white mode ?

Comment: @membersound Edited, please check the new answer and test it

Comment: Adding lines in `<module>/src/test/resources/logback-test.xml` does change the test  output: I can see white INFO or DEBUG messages from Spring if I turn it on and these messages disappear when I turn it OFF. However, the red INFO messages during test startup still appear independent of the setting in logback-test.xml. It leads me to believe that there is some "initializing" phase that happens before logback-test.xml is loaded.

Comment: @Jodiug I think the logs that you're talking about, is for logback initialization, with my solution the other noisy logs (like in question) will be ignored (as you wanted)

Comment: The red INFO messages are from Spring and are exactly the same as the ones posted in the original question. The original question, and my question, is how to suppress these red stderr INFO messages. I really appreciate your effort, but your solution does not suppress these messages

Answer (score 3):

You will need to create one **logback-test.xml** in your **\test\resources** directory, contents of this file can be following

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration />
```

**Why empty ?**

Because you'd not want anything to be logged at this point in time, hence - empty configuration.

If you wish to find out more specific you can see some [examples here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing-log-level#configuring-logback)

Comment: I will try this, though I am still missing something - this silences the above messages but may also hide other, useful messages. INFO logs should normally go to stdout. Do you know why the log output shows up in red (stderr) and not white (stdout)?

Comment: ^ Cannot edit, but this method does not work for me. I still get INFO output in stderr even though `logback-test.xml` is present - I suspect the logback config is only read after these messages appear.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: I know, this is not a real answer, but way too long for a comment.

Using the log4j dependency didn't changed much in my output.

My POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My application.properties is empty, so no log config there.

My test

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT, properties = "logging.level.root=")
public class DemoApplicationTests
{

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        System.out.println("Katzenbilder sind doof");
    }

}
```

Running the tests from within IntelliJ with `logging.level.root=OFF` leads to this output

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

##### Optional[Hallo Welt]
##### Hallo Welt
Katzenbilder sind doof

Process finished with exit code 0
```

The two lines with `#####`are System.out.println() from a test bean.

Running the test with `logging.level.root=INFO` I get the expected clutter of Spring log messages.

I also, just for the sake of validation, put `logging.level.root=INFO` in my application.properties and had it to `OFF` in the test. No clutter, just the System.out.println() messages.

Comment: You can disable the banner using `spring.main.banner-mode=off`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a configuration issue with `log4j2`. Pls refer the hierarchy of `log4j2` configuration [here](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html).

In your case `log4j2` is initially configured using `log4j2.properties` or `log4j2.xml` available under `src/main/resources` and hence `INFO` logs are printed on console. The logging level will be changed to `OFF` only when the test class is loaded, which is done only after startup logging noise is already printed.

To avoid any startup logging noise, pls add a `log4j2.properties` or `log4j2.xml` under `src/test/resources` with `root` logging level as `ERROR` *(I would not prefer setting it to `OFF` as this would also suppress any errors).*

I was not able to reproduce the error where startup logs were written to `stderr`. Pls check if you have set `dest` property to `err` in `log4j2` configuration. This can force the startup logs to be written to `stderr`.

> **EDIT #1**
>
> Sharing my `log4j2.xml` configuration placed under `src/main/resources` for your reference.
>
> Under `src/test/resources`, `<Root level="info">` is changed to `<Root level="error">`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN" monitorInterval="0">

  <Properties>
    <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
      %d | %5p | [%t] | %c:%M(%L) | %m %n
    </Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    <Console name="ConsoleAppender">
      <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="info">
      <AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>

</Configuration>
```

Comment: I tried adding a log4j2.xml, logj4.xml, log4j2-test.xml, log4j-test.xml to the test resource folder, with log appenders and different root log levels. Unfortunately it has no effect. This is what a failed test looks like: https://i.imgur.com/xNlj9Pu.jpg

Comment: Can you pls share your `log4j2.xml` config. Let me check with the exact same configuration. I did not face any issues of having logs written to `stderr`.

Comment: I found this one online, and added some `AAAAAAA`'s to the log format to make sure I noticed if it would change: https://pastebin.com/raw/D7Nfspmj

Comment: I tried with your configuration in `src/test/resources` by changing `root` logging level to `info` and it works fine for me. Logs are written to `stdout` and not `stderr`. :)

Comment: Unfortunately I still see the same INFO logs in red, using your configuration in `src/test/resources/log4j2.xml`. I did a search on the word `dest` in our code base and that also came up empty... I guess it's time to post a minimal example and start A/B testing

Comment: @Jodiug I guess we will have to do that. Btw, which version of IntelliJ are you using? I am wondering can this be a bug in IntelliJ. Though unlikely but just a thought. I am using `IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.2 (Community Edition)` and spring version `2.0.4.RELEASE`

Answer (score 0):

Good night, lot's of answers here.. Regarding the log level configuration - all seem valid.
But your problem may be more the maven build to be noisy - why don't you try to redirect the surefire's test output into separate files, one for each test ?

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile

https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html#redirectTestOutputToFile

This could be nicely done globally as:

```
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <redirectTestOutputToFile>true</redirectTestOutputToFile>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
</pluginManagement>
```

Comment: Hi Diogo, thanks for your answer I had not tried this yet. With test output redirected to a file, the output of the actual test disappears but the red INFO messages upon the initialization of a SpringBootTest are still there!